# Setting a hardwarebreakpoint in multithreaded application doesn't fire

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, debugging, breakpoints

I wrote a little debugger for analysing and looging certain problems. Now I implemented a hardwarebreakpoint for detecting the access of a memory address being overwritten. When I run my debugger with a test process, then everything works fine. When I access the address, the breakpoint fires and the callstack is logged. The problem is, when I run the same against an application running multiple threads. I'm replicating the breakpoint into every thread that gets created and also the main thread. None of the functions report an error and everything looks fine, but when the address is accessed, the breakpoint never fires.

So I wonder if there is some documentation where this is described or if there are additionaly things that I have to do in case of a multithreaded application.

The function to set the breakpoint is this:

```
#ifndef _HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT_H
#define _HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT_H

#include "breakpoint.h"

#define MAX_HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT     4

#define REG_DR0_BIT                 1
#define REG_DR1_BIT                 4
#define REG_DR2_BIT                 16
#define REG_DR3_BIT                 64


class HardwareBreakpoint : public Breakpoint
{
public:
    typedef enum 
    {
        REG_INVALID     = -1,
        REG_DR0         =  0,
        REG_DR1         =  1,
        REG_DR2         =  2,
        REG_DR3         =  3
    } Register;

    typedef enum
    {
        CODE,
        READWRITE,
        WRITE,
    } Type;

    typedef enum
    {
        SIZE_1,
        SIZE_2,
        SIZE_4,
        SIZE_8,
    } Size;

    typedef struct 
    {
        void *pAddress;
        bool bBusy;
        Type nType;
        Size nSize;
        Register nRegister;
    } Info;

public:
    HardwareBreakpoint(HANDLE hThread);
    virtual ~HardwareBreakpoint(void);

    /**
     * Sets a hardware breakpoint. If no register is free or an error occured
     * REG_INVALID is returned, otherwise the hardware register for the given breakpoint.
     */
    HardwareBreakpoint::Register set(void *pAddress, Type nType, Size nSize);
    void remove(void *pAddress);
    void remove(Register nRegister);

    inline Info const *getInfo(Register nRegister) const { return &mBreakpoint[nRegister]; }

private:
    typedef Breakpoint super;

private:
    Info mBreakpoint[MAX_HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT];
    size_t mRegBit[MAX_HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT];
    size_t mRegOffset[MAX_HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT];
};
#endif // _HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT_H

void SetBits(DWORD_PTR &dw, size_t lowBit, size_t bits, size_t newValue)
{
    DWORD_PTR mask = (1 << bits) - 1; 
    dw = (dw & ~(mask << lowBit)) | (newValue << lowBit);
}

HardwareBreakpoint::HardwareBreakpoint(HANDLE hThread)
    : super(hThread)
{
    mRegBit[REG_DR0] = REG_DR0_BIT;
    mRegBit[REG_DR1] = REG_DR1_BIT;
    mRegBit[REG_DR2] = REG_DR2_BIT;
    mRegBit[REG_DR3] = REG_DR3_BIT;

    CONTEXT ct;
    mRegOffset[REG_DR0] = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&ct.Dr0) - reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&ct);
    mRegOffset[REG_DR1] = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&ct.Dr1) - reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&ct);
    mRegOffset[REG_DR2] = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&ct.Dr2) - reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&ct);
    mRegOffset[REG_DR3] = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&ct.Dr3) - reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&ct);

    memset(&mBreakpoint[0], 0, sizeof(mBreakpoint));
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT; i++)
        mBreakpoint[i].nRegister = (Register)i;
}

HardwareBreakpoint::Register HardwareBreakpoint::set(void *pAddress, Type nType, Size nSize)
{
    CONTEXT ct = {0};
    super::setAddress(pAddress);

    ct.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
    if(!GetThreadContext(getThread(), &ct))
        return HardwareBreakpoint::REG_INVALID;

    size_t iReg = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT; i++)
    {
        if (ct.Dr7 & mRegBit[i])
            mBreakpoint[i].bBusy = true;
        else
            mBreakpoint[i].bBusy = false;
    }

    Info *reg = NULL;

    // Address already used?
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT; i++)
    {
        if(mBreakpoint[i].pAddress == pAddress)
        {
            iReg = i;
            reg = &mBreakpoint[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if(reg == NULL)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_HARDWARE_BREAKPOINT; i++)
        {
            if(!mBreakpoint[i].bBusy)
            {
                iReg = i;
                reg = &mBreakpoint[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // No free register available
    if(!reg)
        return HardwareBreakpoint::REG_INVALID;

    *(void **)(((char *)&ct)+mRegOffset[iReg]) = pAddress;
    reg->bBusy = true;

    ct.Dr6 = 0;
    int st = 0;
    if (nType == CODE)
        st = 0;
    if (nType == READWRITE)
        st = 3;
    if (nType == WRITE)
        st = 1;

    int le = 0;
    if (nSize == SIZE_1)
        le = 0;
    else if (nSize == SIZE_2)
        le = 1;
    else if (nSize == SIZE_4)
        le = 3;
    else if (nSize == SIZE_8)
        le = 2;

    SetBits(ct.Dr7, 16 + iReg*4, 2, st);
    SetBits(ct.Dr7, 18 + iReg*4, 2, le);
    SetBits(ct.Dr7, iReg*2, 1, 1);

    ct.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
    if(!SetThreadContext(getThread(), &ct))
        return REG_INVALID;

    return reg->nRegister;
}
```

I'm setting the breakpoint in the main debugger loop whenever a new thread is created `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` but looking at the sourcecode of `GDB` it seems not to be done there, so maybe that is to early?

Comment: You are missing a Windows tag... On Linux, you'll use `ptrace`

Comment: Oh, yes. I added the tag now. Originaly I thought there might be somethign wrong with setting the breakpoint in the hardware.

Comment: It appears that you're setting the hardware breakpoint yourself using your own code. I'm curious why that is if you're using GDB (which I believe supports hardware breakpoints on Windows)

Comment: I was using the source code of GDB, because I hoped to gain some insight, but it's incredible complex to dig in just for that. The reason why I wrote my own code, is because this is my own small debugger, for analyzing production problems where I can not install/run a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found the answer to this problem.

In the debug event loop, I'm monitoring the events that windows sends me. One of those events is `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` which I used to set the hardware breakpoint whenever a new thread was created.

The problem is, that the notification of this event comes before the thread got actually started. So Windows is setting the context for the first time AFTER this event is sent, which of course overwrites any context data that I have set before.

The solution I implemented now is, when a `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` comes I put a software breakpoint at the start adress of the thread, so that the first instruction is my breakpoint. When I receive the breakpoint event, I restore the original code and install the hardware breakpoint, which now fires fine.

If there is a better solution, I'm all ears. :)

Answer (score 1):

Addition to your own answer:

You mentioned setting a software breakpoint as soon as the `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` fires since you can't set the registers at that point.
During my own testing I noticed that it is in fact possible to set the debug registers this early.
As the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-create_thread_debug_info#members) mention:

> the debugger has THREAD_GET_CONTEXT, THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, and
> THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME access to the thread, allowing the debugger to
> read from and write to the registers of the thread and control
> execution of the thread.

The thing that's important for this to work is to suspend the thread before setting the registers.
So things should happen in this order:

1. `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` fires
2. check for valid handle
3. call `SuspendThread`
4. Set the debug register by reading and writing the context
5. call `ResumeThread`

This way it's not required to set a software breakpoint. I noticed you didn't mention suspending the thread in the question and your answer so I guess you forgot about that in that step.